# Rotation of string character inside the Label

Tags: .net, maui

I am working with net maui Label control. I want to rotate only the string character inside the label without rotating the label. How can I achieve this?

I want implementation to rotate the text inside the label without rotating the Label?

Comment: Not possible, better use more than one label inside HorizontalStackLayout

Comment: How would you know that the Label is or is not rotated? Why is it such a problem that the Label is or is not being rotated?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Rotate it like what? Like grad by grad or 90/180?

Comment: Not grad by grad I want to rotate 0,90,180,270 degrees . The contraint is only text inside the label should rotate, not the label

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom control that achieves what you're trying to do.

Something like this.

`RotatableLabel.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.RotatableLabel">
    <HorizontalStackLayout
        Spacing="5"
        x:Name="LabelContainer" />
</ContentView>
```

`RotatableLabel.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class RotatableLabel : ContentView
{
    public RotatableLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string? _text;
    public string? Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            HandleRotation();
        }
    }

    private int _textRotation;
    public int TextRotation
    {
        get => _textRotation;
        set
        {
            _textRotation = value;
            HandleRotation();
        }
    }

    private void HandleRotation()
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return;
        
        LabelContainer.Clear();
        foreach (var c in Text)
        {
            LabelContainer.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = $"{c}",
                Rotation = TextRotation
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and you would use it like this.

```xml
<test:RotatableLabel
    Text="Hello World"
    TextRotation="90" />
```

It surely can be enhanced, for example using BindableProperties, calculating better the spacing between letters and handling `Label` properties, but it's a good starting point.